Indexed in Bing and Yahoo Search but not in Google although Sitemap is accessed by Google Bot
My website is indexed in Yahoo and Bing. If I search for website, I could see both Yahoo and Bing show it as first result.
In Google Search I do not see my website indexed at all. I have tried the below ways.
Added the sitemap and it was accessed by google as per Google Search Console

When Click Indexed Report, below is seen:

And the below:

As you see, it falls under 5XX errors, but when I try Test Live URL, it works and could see the proper screenshot too.
No matter how many times I submit the sitemap, still it falls under 5XX errors.
But I could access these URLs in the sitemap without any 5XX, 4XX, 3XX errors.

Can anyone assist me if I`m missing out any sort of things for Google Indexing.
Thank you.
